# Abbreviating sets of compounds with leading characters in common

Tags: orthography, compounds, coordination

I [recently asked a question about on- and kun-yomi](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/similar-%E9%9F%B3-%E8%A8%93%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF-coincidence-or-something-more) and in building the title guessed at how the two compounds involved could be contracted; landing on 「音・訓読み」.

Is this indeed the correct way of abbreviating something like 「音読み・訓読み」, and if so, when can it be used?

If not; what construction should be used?

Comment: It's valid; see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27515/7810

Comment: 音読み and 訓読み can be abbreviated as 音訓, but I don't think that works for any two (or more) arbitrary words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no restriction in making this kind of ad hoc portmanteau compounds, as long as all original words have parallel structure. That said, it's more natural if the non-common parts are contrastive in meaning.

> [上下水道](http://www.city.kawasaki.jp/800/cmsfiles/contents/0000035/35839/) "water(works) and sewerage" < 上水道 + 下水道
>   [開閉会式](http://news.livedoor.com/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E4%BA%94%E8%BC%AA%E3%81%AE%E9%96%8B%E9%96%89%E4%BC%9A%E5%BC%8F/topics/keyword/37149/) "opening and closing ceremony" < 開会式 + 閉会式
>   [視触覚](http://www.moguravr.com/unlimited-corridor-movie/) "visuo-haptic" < 視覚 + 触覚

It doesn't need to be exactly two components:

> [都道府県庁所在地](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%83%BD%E9%81%93%E5%BA%9C%E7%9C%8C%E5%BA%81%E6%89%80%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%B0) "seat of the office of [都/道/府/県](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefectures_of_Japan)" (i.e. capitol)

or being the first character:

> [輸出入](http://law.e-gov.go.jp/htmldata/S27/S27HO299.html) "import and export" < 輸出 + 輸入

But an interpunct (・) is required when the result spelling causes confusion (colliding with existing words):

> [北{きた}・東{ひがし}アジア](http://researchmap.jp/jor5kvumk-45644/) "North and East Asia" cf. 北東{ほくとう} "northeast"
>   [環状1・2号線](http://www.ur-net.go.jp/east/order/kouzi/pdf/ur2008e_ord0324_01.pdf) "the ring road 1/2"

In your case, however, the word 音訓読み is already reserved for "a type of 2-kanji word where the former is read in 音読み and the latter in 訓読み", so you should avoid this wording (but should be understood with aid of the context). Fortunately, as mentioned in a comment, what you mean can be conveyed by another word [音訓](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34326/meaning/m0u/).

Comment: Can the interpunct be used even if it's not necessary, or should this not be done?

Comment: @WillihamTotland In my experience, interpunct is rarely seen if no possibility of confusion, but there's no rule that you can't, either.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. Is this common in Jp?

Examples in English :

- . . . control issues in ground-, water-, and air-based robots.
- nineteenth- and twentieth-century.
- e.g. two-, three-, or four-fold increase.
- "investor-owned and -operated".

When I do net-search with 「音・訓読み」, the results include few or no hits indicating the meaning 「音読み・訓読み」.

音・訓読み (and especially without the dot as 音訓読み) often means 重箱読み.

> 中学入試の定番「重箱読み」と「湯桶読み」 - Pickup！教育のヒント - 教育の ...
>
> education.mag2.com/osusume/2009/01/216.html
>
> 重箱読み（音・訓読み）…

Title of academic paper:  現代日本語の音・訓読み分けの機構を論じ、「漢語・和語形態素の相補的分布」に及ぶ.